# Multiple Sections UITableViewController with PFObjects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am building a very simple timetable iOS app to test out **Swift** and **Parse.com** as a backend.

I have an object type in my Parse database called "Class" (for school classes). These are simple objects that contain a `name` and `dayOfWeek` (Monday - Friday).

I want to display these similar to the iOS Calendar app 'list view', with a section of each day: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday (not actual dates like the Calendar app, just the week day name).

[image: iOS Calendar List View]

Then I want to display under each day, only the PFObjects returned from a query with same `dayOfWeek` as the relevant section.

I tried achieving this with a PFQueryTableViewController, but got weird issues with no section names and random empty cells throughout the table.

I believe that I need to take the following approach, but so help would be highly appreciated.

1. Retrieve a `PFQuery` of all my `Class` objects
2. Set `numberOfSectionsInTable` to 7 (one for each day)
3. Set `titleForSection` to appropriate names
4. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, cycle through returned Class objects, allocating each to the correct section based on `dayOfWeek`. **Not sure how to do this part.**

I have searched around and found that there seems to be no clear tutorials or documentation on how to show PFObjects from a PFQuery in multiple sections, sorted by one of the values of the object.

Any help would be appreciated. I believe this will help a lot of other people too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create dynamic sections with a 2D array containing the name of the current section and an array to hold the the items. 
 
You can then simply call

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return sectionItems.items[section].count
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return sectionItems.items[section].count
    }
```

sectionItems can be created using this class with takes a string and an array as a parameter

```
class SectionItems:NSObject{
    var sections:[String] = []
    var items:[[String]] = []

    func addSection(section: String, item:[String]){
        sections = sections + [section]
        items = items + [item]
}

}
```

You can the call the function by using

```
self.sectionItems.addSection("Intro", item: self.intro)
```